# Docopt: why this usage is not parsed?

Tags: docopt

My usage:

```
Usage:
  prog at (<v1> [<v1>]) [(before <v2>)] (alarm|email)
```

My command line args:

```
at 4 alarm
```

It seems clear to me that the appearance of `at` and `alarm` locates the ambiguous value `4` to be either `v1` or `v2`. And since `v2` will always be led by `before`, we can tell that `4` is `v1`.

However, it's not parsed. See me [try it](http://try.docopt.org/?doc=Usage%3A%0D%0A++prog+at+%28%3Cv1%3E+%5B%3Cv1%3E%5D%29+%5B%28before+%3Cv2%3E%29%5D+%28alarm%7Cemail%29&argv=at+4+alarm).

Anyone know why it's not parsed, and how I can make it parse with minimal change to the usage? Note that in the usage, I'm trying to achieve a more natural language kind of interface, so rearranging the syntax might be a bit difficult.

*EDIT:*

A few attempts:

- It parses if I [remove the `(alarm|email)` part](http://try.docopt.org/?doc=Usage%3A%0D%0A%20%20prog%20at%20%28%3Cv1%3E%20%5B%3Cv1%3E%5D%29%20%5B%28before%20%3Cv2%3E%29%5D&argv=at%204)
- It does *not* parse if I [specify the `before` clause in the args](http://try.docopt.org/?doc=Usage%3A%0D%0A%20%20prog%20at%20%28%3Cv1%3E%20%5B%3Cv1%3E%5D%29%20%5B%28before%20%3Cv2%3E%29%5D%20%28alarm%7Cemail%29&argv=at%204%20before%205%20alarm)
- It does *not* parse if I [do both of the above](http://try.docopt.org/?doc=Usage%3A%0D%0A%20%20prog%20at%20%28%3Cv1%3E%20%5B%3Cv1%3E%5D%29%20%5B%28before%20%3Cv2%3E%29%5D&argv=at%204%20before%205)

Note: Same question asked on github: https://github.com/docopt/docopt/issues/412

Answer (score 0):

[Docopt](http://docopt.org/) doesn't seem to support optional arguments infront of other arguments  unless they are options. Your attempt of parsing `at 4 before alarm` shows that `before` gets recognized as the second positional argument of `<v1>`.

```json
{
  "<v1>": [
    "4", 
    "before"
  ], 
  "<v2>": null, 
  "alarm": true, 
  "at": true, 
  "before": false, 
  "email": false
}
```

I would suggest to move the optional positional arguments to the end.

```
Usage:
  prog [options] (alarm|email) at <v1> [<v1>]

Options:
  -b, --before <v2>   Do something before
```